# how to convert PDF to PNG without converting white background intro transparency

Tags: linux, image-conversion

I am converting a PDF (which I made with R) to a PNG with a command like this:

```
convert -density 200 foo.pdf bar.png
```

This generates a PNG allright, but the white background is transparent in the resulting PNG. This is *not* what I want, I want the background to be white in the PNG as well. How can I achieve this?

Notes:

- I am using Xubuntu.
- What is weird, I did the same sequence on a different linux and computer: first generate picture with R in PDF format, then convert from PDF to PNG, and on that installation it does not convert the white background into transparency, just as I want it. But, I do not know where the difference is caused (R, convert or what).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add this setting:

> -flatten

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background)

Comment: Note that if the original PDF has multiple pages, this will result in the content of different pages superimposed on each other.

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to add 
        **-alpha remove -alpha off**
because -flatten merges all pages if any and would be depreciated ( **-layers flatten** is recommended )

Answer (score 0):

This is an R solution, but you can also take care of this by generating the graphics in R.  For example, the `pdf()` function has an argument `bg` that allows you to change the background color of your graphics.  You can also generate png files directly using the `png` function.

R documentation links:

- [`pdf()` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html)
- [`png()` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html)
- [`dev.copy()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev2.html) is also useful for copying the same graphics to multiple formats.